# WC()->cart->add_to_cart issue here?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm using this function to add product variations to the cart programmatically.

```
function add_to_cart($product_id, $variation_id, $variation_data) {
    
global $woocommerce;

$quantity   =   $variation_data["article_quantity"];
$count      =   WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
echo "<br> Count : " .$count;

WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id );

$new_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
echo "<br> New count : " .$new_count;
    
if ($new_count == $count + 1 ) {
    echo "<br> Product added";

} else {
    echo "<br> Can't add product";
}
}
```

All variations added by this function are successfully created programmatically and works fine.

The problem is that, for some reason, this function doesn't work in the same way every time.
In the same user session (all sessions and cookies are checked) Sometimes the variation is successfully added, sometimes I get an empty cart, and sometimes it shows me the cart that was deleted 10 minutes ago (probably a session cache / deactivated / but still have the same issue).

When I try to add the variation that I just create programmatically by using the add to cart button, all works. No issue. That means that the variation and all its meta exists and well linked to the parent product.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?
I'm not a dev.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Where do you call this function?

Comment: I'm working in an implementation of a 3d configurator in a woocommerce based store.
This function is inside a file (add_to_card.php) located in (mysite.com/configurator/) in the same domain where wordpress/woocommerce are installed (mysite.com).
Wordpress core is loaded by :
require_once("../wp-load.php");
require_once("../wp-admin/includes/post.php");
require_once('../wp-admin/includes/image.php');

As I mentioned, all other WordPress functions are working and create products and its variations successfully.

Comment: Read this: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/add-product-to-cart-programmatically.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers @Mr-Jo.
I did.
This blog post was my reference.
The only thing that I need to change now, thank you, is to delete global $woocommerce;  since I'm using WC()->cart instead of $woocommerce->cart.